# Convert Mysql query with subquery to web2py DAL possible?

Tags: sql, select, web2py, data-access-layer

New to Python and Web2py specially. Having difficulties to convert to `DAL` this:

```
select t.id, t.gp_pro_id, t.gp_historicdate 
from course t where t.gp_historicdate = 
(select MAX(a.gp_historicdate) 
from course a where a.id = t.id)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I just don't want to use `executesql` but if it is not possible to translate then I will.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more details about the structure of `course` table?

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake!

```
db(db.course.gp_historicdate == db.course.gp_historicdate.max()).select(db.course.id, db.course.gp_pro_id, db.course.gp_historicdate)
```

[Check the official documentation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#sum--avg--min--max-and-len)